# Is it possible in highmaps(highcharts) to So that the territory of Russia is displayed in full?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible in highmaps(highcharts) to transfer part of the territory of the country Russia (near Alaska (USA)) from the left side and attach it to the territory of Russia on the right side. So that the territory of Russia is displayed in full?

```
image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UuKy.png
```

demo here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/y8b3emhj/1/)

Comment: I wouldn't completely rule out the possibility, but it's certainly not feasible by default and somewhat goes against the conventional approach. The -180° to 180° longitude range is a common convention for global maps and that kind of maps and projections are implemented in Highcharts. The only projection that could potentially align with your requirements is the orthographic projection.

Comment: It is necessary to change this particular map, the orthographic projection unfortunately does not fit. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: As Seiryu V said, editing json is the idea; additionally, you can also read about custom maps here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it but it is somewhat tedious.

You must take the JSON, save it in a git repository for example and modify the coordinates you want.

Comment: is there an example of how to do this in any small territotie?

Comment: Before trying to change the coordinates, check this link to see if any of the maps work for you.
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

Comment: I used this editor to see the map vectors
https://mapshaper.org/